# Looking for a way to find the proportional growth rate in time for any given notation

Tags: asymptotics

I am wondering if there is a straight forward way to illustrate the proportional growth rate in time (or space) for any given notation such as $O(n^2)$ or $O(logn)$?

My initial thought is that $O(n^2)$ would be equal to $O(n)*O(n)$ but I'm sure that's completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean. In fact, $O(n^2)=O(n)\cdot O(n)$, i.e. every fucntion $f\in O(n^2)$ can be written as $f=gh$ with $g,h\in O(n)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen to tell you the truth, the question I'm trying to solve is super vague too: "The notation O(n3) means that its algorithm’s time (or space) growth rate is
proportional to ______."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ iff:

> There exist constants $c,n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$, if $c>0$, then $0 \le f(n) \le c \cdot g(n)$.

Also, recall that $y$ is **proportional** to $x$ simply if $y=kx$ for some constant $k$.

Thus, suppose some algorithm had a running time of $f(n)=O(n^3)$. Then we can conclude that this algorithm's (time or space) growth rate is proportional to $n^3$. For example, it might be the case that $f(n)=4n^3$ or $f(n)=50n^3$.